# Why is my picture appearing in the rich text editor but not in the PDF version?

Tags: graphics

I am using overleaf. I have inputted the following code to show an image:

```
\begin{figure}[http]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{pickering.png}
    \caption{Table of Statistics}
\end{figure}
```

The image will show up in the rich text editor but not in the PDF version. My compiler gives the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.86\includegraphics
                      [width=5in]{pickering.png}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I’m afraid I don’t understand what you mean when you say that the image shows up “in the rich text editor”.  Also, you shouldn’t post code fragments, but a complete Minimal Working Example.  **Edit:**  Oh, wait!  You say you are using overleaf.  In that case, I’m not the right person to help you, I’m sorry.

Comment: Hi! I'm using the rich text editor in Overleaf! What do you mean by Minimal Working Example?

Comment: you have not shown the full error message so it does not say what is undefined, so we have to guess a bit.. have you loaded the graphicx package?

Comment: Okay. I edited my question. This is the first time I'm using Overleaf/LaTex. Let me know if my question is still unclear.

Comment: It looks like you have not loaded the `graphicx` package (as @DavidCarlisle has already supposed).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for your help guys. It is not working.

Comment: About the [minimal working example (MWE)]. (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Most probably you must add   `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the document preamble (somewhere between the  `\documentclass` definition and the `\begin` of the `{document}`), but without see a example, as minimal as possible, but complete (with preamble)  this could be a  talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: As start point for your MWE please test: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[http]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{pickering.png}
    \caption{Table of Statistics}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`. Then add to preamble of this MWE other packages from your real document. if it still working remove from MWE option `demo`. If you will get you picture on the page, the your problem is solved.

Comment: **now working. Sorry typo. The solutoins from GuM and @David worked! My apologies!